# How to separate individual file names in a list when they contain spaces

Tags: regex, bash, shell, unix, awk

I am writing a bash script to generate a list of duplicate files based on their SHA-1 hashes. I then wish to remove these duplicates from an array which contains all the file names in a directory, so I can copy only non-duplicate files to a new directory.

The issue I am facing is that a number of files contain spaces in their names, and so I don't know how to separate them from a list.

```
# Fill array with all file names in directory
files=(*)

#find all repeating sha-1 values
repeats=$(echo $(find -type f -exec sha1sum '{}' ';' | sort | uniq --all-repeated=separate -w 40 ))
```

Due to the spaces in the names, the output takes the following format:

`1386d44b318730ffa98a34176d4e8b7eab8e02a4 ./Forensic Scripting 01 - Introduction to Developing Software and Shell Scripting (1).ppt 1386d44b318730ffa98a34176d4e8b7eab8e02a4 ./Forensic Scripting 01 - Introduction to Developing Software and Shell Scripting.ppt 2f4fc07ee944d666c34b0dfeeda90ad1c5cb9e71 ./kravica_waterfall_bosnia (copy).jpg 2f4fc07ee944d666c34b0dfeeda90ad1c5cb9e71 ./kravica_waterfall_bosnia.jpg 45f478cedd980ff2313f05fd0997a08492b9b21b ./canada-niagarafalls_-5 (another copy).jpg 45f478cedd980ff2313f05fd0997a08492b9b21b ./canada-niagarafalls_-5 (copy).jpg 45f478cedd980ff2313f05fd0997a08492b9b21b ./canada-niagarafalls_-5.jpg a3c6c5b749ce43cc3dade17230580b5ecf4d1557 ./frink (copy).png a3c6c5b749ce43cc3dade17230580b5ecf4d1557 ./frink.png d6039f1932dc2bb6fecfa41c02a7e9bc6656c621 ./UK - Associate Guide (Final Version -Effective Date 13 Feb 2012) (copy).pdf d6039f1932dc2bb6fecfa41c02a7e9bc6656c621 ./UK - Associate Guide (Final Version -Effective Date 13 Feb 2012).pdf`

How can I wrap filenames in quotes so that they are clearly identified as one block, so that I am able to then perform operations based on these lists?

Comment: That `echo` is pointless. And you can't do this without operating on a line-by-line basis (and even that only works if your filenames can't contain newlines). If they can you need NUL-delimited entries. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Answer (score 1):

If you have bash 4, you can use associative arrays, which make this problem simpler. (bash 3 solution below).

For example:

```
# The output array
declare -a nondups=()
# An associative array which maps checksum to filename
declare -A checksum

for file in *; do
  # Make sure it's not a directory
  if [[ -f "$file" ]]; then
    chk=$(sha1sum "$file")
    # We just want the checksum
    chk=${chk%% *}
    if ! [[ -v checksum[$chk] ]]; then
    # -v doesn't work on subscripts before v4.3. Alternative:
    # if [[ -z ${checksum[$chk]} ]]; then
      # We've never hit this checksum before
      nondups+=($file)  # Add it to the list
      checksum[$chk]=1  # Mark checksum as seen
    fi
  fi
done
```

If you want to do a recursive file listing, as `find` would do, you can use the `globstar` shell option to do a recursive listing. Just make sure you have done `shopt -s globstar` and then change the `for` loop to `for file in **; do`

If you don't have bash 4, you can make `checksum` a simple string variable, and check it with a substring match:

```
if [[ $checksum == *${chk}* ]]; then
  # We've never hit this checksum before
  nondups+=($file)  # Add it to the list
  checksum+=" $chk" # Mark checksum as seen
fi
```

Comment: [`-v` does work on arrays and associative arrays since Bash 4.3](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/CHANGES).

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not quite what you asked, but personally I would suggest - use perl.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Digest::SHA1 qw ( sha1_hex );

my $search = "*"; 

my %digests; 

while ( my $filename = glob ( $search ) ) {

    next if -d $filename;
    open ( my $input, "<", $filename ) or warn $!;
    my $sha_sum = sha1_hex ( <$input> ); 
    close ( $input );
    if ( $digests{$sha_sum} ) { print "$filename matches $digests{$sha_sum}\n"; }
    $digests{$sha_sum} = $filename;

    print "$filename $sha_sum\n";
 }
```

That way - you can manipulate `$filename` as you see fit, without having to worry about spaces etc. (This doesn't print all the duplicates, because it only keeps track of the last one seen).

Once that's done, you can:

```
foreach my $filename ( values %digests ) { 
   print "$filename is unique\n";
}
```

(Because any non unique entries in `%digests` have been removed)